# Replace database in new application version

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter

I build an app with existing database file. After first run DB is copied from asstets folder. I would like to be able to replace database but only if it has changed. I have tried to use version parameter in openDatabase() function, but it does not work.

```
initDB() async {
    String databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'db.sqlite');

    Database db;
    try {
      db = await openDatabase(path, readOnly: false);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error $e");
    }
    if (db == null) {
      // Should happen only the first time you launch your application
      print("Creating new copy from asset");

      // Copy from asset
      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "db.sqlite"));
      List<int> bytes =
          data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
      await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);

      // open the database
      db = await openDatabase(path, readOnly: false);
    } else {
      print("Opening existing database");
    }
    return db;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the database property `user_version` and check when it has changed. To set it you would use `PRAGMA user_version = {version};` and to query the current version you would use `PRAGMA user_version;`

Answer (score 0):

> add onCreate and onUpgrade listeners.

```
var theDb = await openDatabase(path,
    version: 14, onCreate: _onCreate, onUpgrade: _onUpgrade);

void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
//load your db from assets
print("Created tables");
}
//Drop and create tables onUpgrade or Alter.
FutureOr _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
//code your changes to the db like alter table queries, or drop and create.
}
```